# django find object from url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Supposing that I have something like that in my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^task/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', taskview, name='taskview')
```

How can django help me extract '10' (or `{"pk": 10}`) from reading any matching URL string like:

- `/task/10/`
- `/task/10///`
- `/task/10/dddd/dddd/dddwwwww/wwwwq/qqqqqqw/qwead/?adawd=awodawdoij`

?

(FYI when I say "reading any URL string" I mean that I am not receiving a request on those urls, but rather that I have such a string in my code on which I have to perform the aforementioned keyword extraction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out:

```
from django.urls import resolve
resolve(url).kwargs
```

Comment: Now in new versions of Django it looks like:

from django.urls import resolve